# Can I multiply samples' scores in PCA to project new data?

Tags: r, pca

I have m1 rows (samples) and n columns (variables) in matrix A, and m2 rows and n columns in matrix B (n>m1 and n>m2). Normally, I performed PCA on matrix A and got a low-dimensional representation of m1 samples, and then projected m2 samples into the low-dimensional subspace via multiplying the rotation matrix.

Now I am thinking about what if I perform PCA on matrix A's transposition, and then I will get n variables (now they are *samples*)'s score matrix **M**. My question is, is it correct to project matrix B via multiplying **M**, and what is the difference between these two approaches?

Thank you in advance!